# buttons do not appear in applications like evince, etc. image viewer. in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

buttons do not appear in applications like evince, etc. image viewer. in ubuntu 13.10
I installed ubuntu 13.10 recently I found many bugs, the one that most affected me I can not print from applications such as Evince, photo viewer that have to do with Gnome, from firefox, thunderbird I can print perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The menu appears to have been relocated to the right side, inside the gear symbol. You'll find all the options and printing menu there.